# Signing AWS API Gateway Request using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, amazon-web-services, signature

I've been searching for ways to restrict access to an API made for using a AWS Lambda function written on javascript.

I've found documentation on how to use AWS Signature S4, but I still do not understand it.

According to [creating a signature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html), after applying the pseudocode I should get the signature to be placed on the header.

I've found the following code that addresses this point:

```js
// Example of signature generator

var crypto = require("crypto-js");

function getSignatureKey(Crypto, key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate = Crypto.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
    var kRegion = Crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    var kService = Crypto.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    var kSigning = Crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}

console.log(getSignatureKey(crypto,'secretkey','date','us-east-2','iam'));
```

Here comes my first question, I do not know what should be the output of getSignatureKey()? This is because on the documentation it is a very long string, while the output I got was {words:[x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x],sigBytes: 32},where the x are random numbers.

Moreover, after getting the signature and filling the header for the request with the "authorization" field and others, how do I filter unproper requests? Do I have to create a policy for the AWS API so it only allows signed requests? Here I guess I should follow [Signing Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/).

Thanks!

Comment: From the page you cited: "The following example shows the derived signing key that results from this sequence of HMAC hash operations. **This shows the hexadecimal representation of each byte in the binary signing key.**"  Your 32 "words" (bytes) are equivalent to 64 characters of hex.  The hex representation is eyeball-friendly, but you don't need the signing key in hex form -- that's only for illustration.

Comment: Thanks! Still, if I do not need the signature in hexadecimal, what's the format of the one to introduce in the header?

Comment: `getSignatureKey` returns the key you will use to sign the canonical request, not the signature itself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple implementation of Signed URL's. aws-cloudfront-sign package offers simpler implementation.

```
var cfsign = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');

var signingParams = {
  keypairId: process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,
  privateKeyString: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  // Optional - this can be used as an alternative to privateKeyString
  privateKeyPath: '/path/to/private/key',
  expireTime: 1426625464599
}

// Generating a signed URL
var signedUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl(
  'http://example.cloudfront.net/path/to/s3/object', 
  signingParams
);
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/creating-amazon-cloudfront-signed-urls-in-node-js/

Purpose of SignedURL is to serve Private Contents.

More details at,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is CloudFront, not Signature V4.

Comment: I'll try it out and comment later the results. Thank you!